# Getting contents of a URL and comparing locally

Tags: python, urllib

I'm looking to get a URL (it returns just one line, no html, just plaintext) every 3000sec. I want to compare it against "previous.txt" and call a function if it's different, then write it to previous.txt.

If it's same, do nothing.
Can someone point me in a place to starting ?I'm not python much before.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

Looking at your question tags you already know that urllib will help. Try `urllib2.urlopen()` to retrieve the data from the URL.

Comparing previous and current contents is as simple as reading in the contents of `previous.txt` and doing a string comparison with whatever you have just retrieved from the URL. If the two strings are different, write the newer one to the file. Look at [`open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) and `read/write` for your file IO needs.

If your Python process is long running, performing the task every 3000 seconds can be done using `time.sleep()` or `signal.alarm()` (or several other ways).